Residue cost on Azure subscription
I have an Azure subscription which I use for private learning or experimentation outside my job. It incurs roughly 1€ in cost every day even when I delete all my resource groups. The three remaining products that show up in the billing are

Premium SSD Managed Disks - P10 - EU West
IP Addresses - Standard IPv4
Load Balancer


Is there a way to avoid that cost? Should I cancel my subscription and only bring it back up when I need it?

I would check to see if you have any resource groups left over with resources in them. I know you said you deleted all resource groups but an Azure resource cannot exist without being in a resource group (other than a subscription or a resource group) so I would check again. These should not be hidden resources either. If that fails, contact billing support. May be worthwhile to check with Azure CLI, if you truly have no resources "az resource list" should show nothing.
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/resource?view=azure-cli-latest#az-resource-list
